# How can I type the command after connect to the Port 5000?

Tags: flask, github, github-actions

1.I was trying to run the UnitTesting on GitHub action. After I run the script to connect the http://127.0.0.1:5000/, I can not input any commands anymore(Unless open another terminal). I was wondering if there is any way can input the command and execute this command after connecting the port http://127.0.0.1:5000/? Or does Github Action support run in different terminals?

2.Here is my yml code:

```
name: UnitTesting
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Python 3
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirement.txt
          
      - name: Run server
        run: |
           cd Flask-backend
           nohup python3 app.py
           sleep
      - name: Run Unit test
        run: |
           pytest
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command does not run in the background.

You need to change it to

```
nohup python3 app.py & &>/dev/null
```

and I believe `sleep` requires an argument, like `sleep 3`

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but change tp nohup python3 app.py & &>/dev/null does not work for me.

Comment: You should try things locally first. This is one way to run it in the background, if it does not work, you might have a different problem.